# Check gconf-client with C

Tags: c, gconf

i use gconf/gconf-client.h in ,y C application, but i don't know, is gconf on users machine. How can i check gconf/gconf-client.h and gconf there or not?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pkg-config. Put this in your `configure.ac`:

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([MYAPPLICATION], [gtk+-2.0 gconf-2.0])
```

In fact, you should already have a line like that in there. Just add `gconf-2.0` to it.

Answer (score 1):

If the code compiles then probably its already installed. Otherwise you can download the package and install it.

If you use the `pkg-config --cflags gconf-2.0` and compile, gcc will give corresponding error if the package doesnt exist in the PKG_CONFIG_PATH.